# Extract values form Django context proseccor

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, dictionary, model

I'm looking for the solution for below problem. I have class Category and SubCategory. In SubCategory I take Category as ForeignKey. By contextprocessor I would like to get values of Category.

```
'''
class SubCategory(models.Model):
    category                = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    sub_category_name       = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    slug                    = models.SlugField(max_length=50, unique=True, null=True, blank=True)

'''
```

By using contextprocessor I would like to extract ForeigKey value to use it later in for loop:

```
'''
from .models import SubCategory


# Create your views here.

def sub_menu_links(request):
     sub_links=SubCategory.objects.all()
     print(dict(sub_links=sub_links))
     return dict(sub_links=sub_links)
'''
```

How can I do it?

Comment: I would like to later on check if Category is in SubCategory.

Comment: If you want to add to your question please [edit] it. Comments are not part of the question; rather they are here to provide a way for people to request clarification. Take the [tour] to see how SE sites work.